# Hotkeys in R studio markdown on Windows 7

Tags: r, markdown, hotkeys, chunks

When working on an Rmarkdown file in Rstudio, adding chunks by hand can become a dragg.
I've learned there are a lot of hotkeys / shortcuts / quickkeys in Rstudio.

However the hotkeys don't seem to work for windows (as far as i've seen of others aswell)
e.g. ctrl+alt+I --> instead of adding a chunck gives the character í

I'd like to be able to use these ctrl+alt+'key' shortcuts.. but how?

- **Operating system** : Windows 7 Home Premium
- **Rstudio** : v0.99.489

Comment: add your windows version and Rstudio version please

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium on Dell XPS with Rstudio 0.99.489, both latest update

Answer (score -1):

The hotkey for adding a chunk in Rstudio markdown is: `ctrl+alt+i`

Operating system : Windows 7 Enterprise
Rstudio : Version 0.99.891

Comment: That should work, it is also what R-studio says but unfortunately this results in the í for me.